# How can I check to avoid gameobject duplication in the hierarchy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class AddTextToObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject[] objectsToNumber;
    public UnityEngine.GameObject text;
    public float yPadding;
    public bool rotateNumbers = false;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public bool textAbove = false;
    public bool textInFront = false;
    public bool textOnFaces = false;

    private List<GameObject> newTexts = new List<GameObject>();
    private MeshRenderer[] renderer;
    private Vector3 newPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        renderer = new MeshRenderer[objectsToNumber.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject newText = Instantiate(text);
            renderer[i] = newText.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x,
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y + renderer[i].bounds.extents.y) + yPadding),
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x + renderer[i].bounds.extents.x) + yPadding),
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y,
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            newText.transform.position = newPos;
            newText.transform.parent = objectsToNumber[i].transform;
            newText.name = objectsToNumber[i].name + " Text";
            newText.tag = "ObjectToAddText";
            newTexts.Add(newText);
            var textmesh = newText.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
            //textmesh.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = i.ToString();
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = objectsToNumber[i].name;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateNumbers == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newTexts.Count; i++)
            {
                newTexts[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's making instantiating when in the editor mode but then if I'm running the game it's instantiating the texts again and then there is a double of texts.

```
GameObject newText = Instantiate(text);
```

And I want to instantiating the texts only once. And if running the game to not create the same texts again.

I'm instantiating the texts gameobjects.

Answer (score 1):

The Unity documentation on the ExecuteAlways attribute shows you how to differentiate logic based on if you're in editor mode or play mode.

```
void Start()
{
    if (Application.IsPlaying(gameObject))
    {
        // Play logic
    }
    else
    {
        // Editor logic
    }
}
```

Snippet taken from here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteAlways.html

Knowing this, you have two options. You could either choose not to instantiate the text when in editor mode, or you can check to see if the text exists when entering Play mode, and if it does, destroy it.

Comment: This will leave garbage/bloat code in the builds. The edit-mode check can also be simplefied. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57684760/1253136) for a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Platform Dependent Compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) so that code intended to run only in the editor is never compiled to a build. This avoids bloat code in the build.

Then, use [`EditorApplication.isPlaying`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-isPlaying.html) to make sure code intended to run only in edit mode does not run in play mode.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR //Avoid garbage in the builds
    //Editor logic
    if(!EditorApplication.isPlaying) //If NOT in play mode
        GameObject newText = Instantiate(text);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no other `TextMesh` objects under the `objectsToNumber[i]` you could simply check first if the object already exists like

```
renderer[i] = GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>();
if(!renderer[i]) renderer[i] = Instantiate(text).GetComponent<TextMesh>();
```

otherwise since we know how you are gonna call the object you could also use `Find` like

```
var child = !objectsToNumber[i].transform.Find(renderer[i].name + " Text");
renderer[i] = child !=null ? child.GetComponnet<TextMesh>() : Instantiate(text).GetComponent<TextMesh>();
```

---

I would change the types to match your target types already e.g. if you make the type of `text`

```
public TextMesh text;
```

then you can omit the `GetComponent` and simply use

```
renderer[i] = Instantiate(text);
```

and it makes also sure you can only reference prefabs/objects with the required component attached.

---

For performance I would also rather use

```
public enum TextPosition
{
    Above,
    InFront,
    OnFaces
}

public TextPosition textPosition;

// and make this a list
private List<MeshRenderer> renderer = new List<MeshRenderer>();
```

and then use

```
private void Start()
{
    foreach(var parent in objectsToNumber)
    {
        var newText = GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>();
        if(!newText) newText = Instantiate(text).GetComponent<TextMesh>();

        renderer.Add(newText);

        switch(textPosition)
        {
            case TextPosition.Above:
                newPos = parent.transform.position + Vector3.up * (renderer[i].bounds.extents.y + yPadding);
                break;

            case TextPosition.InFront:
                newPos = parent.transform.position + Vector3.up * (renderer[i].bounds.extents.x + yPadding);
                break;
        }

        newText.transform.position = newPos;
        newText.transform.parent = parent.transform;
        newText.name = parent.name + " Text";
        newText.tag = "ObjectToAddText";
        newTexts.Add(newText);

        switch(textPosition)
        {
            case TextPosition.Above:
                newText.text = renderer.Count.ToString();
                break;

            case TextPosition.InFront:
                newText.text = parent.name;
                break;
        }
    }
}

and

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateNumbers)
        {
            foreach (var text in newTexts)
            {
                // I would rather assign the correct value to rotationSpeed 
                // instead of multiplying it by 10 afterwards ...
                text.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```